# Ajax posting empty data

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I am trying to make an AJAX post to my Express API.

I am expecting {user:Todd} to be returned in my data object, however whenever i try to log the request body, the object shows as empty./

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/api/test',
  type: 'POST',
  data: ({user: "Todd"})
})
```

I always test my endpoints with cURL as well, and i remember that i needed to pass the header "Content-Type: application/json" for this to work in the past.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/api/test',
  type: 'POST',
  data: ({user: "Todd"}),
  contentType: 'application/json'
})
```

I am listening for requests on my NodeJS server and the above request doesnt even touch my server, while the first one sends empty JSON.

I am officially confused! How can adding a header break my API like this?

Here is the simple source code to my API.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

let app = express();
let port = 3000

app.use(bodyParser.json({
        limit:'150mb'
}));

app.post('/api/test', function(req, res) {
        console.log(req)
        console.log(req.body)
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: "doesnt even touch my server" - what does your dev tools network tab say? Does the request go out there? What is the response?

Comment: im not sure if in `data: ({user: "Todd"})` the parenthesis are causing issues.

Comment: @PedroEstrada the parenthesis not cause the isssue. I just tested it.

Comment: Which express version are you using @Hysii? The reason i ask is because in the latests version of express, we use `app.use(express.json());` for json encoded bodies, instead of using bodyparser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your html script tag

```
const apiHost = "http://localhost:3000";

 $.ajax({
    url: `${apiHost}/api/test`, //add full path of your host
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ //JSON data needs to be stringified before its sent through http.
      'user': 'hello'
    })
  })
```

The reason your server is not receiving the req is because of blocked/restricted **CORS** .

> Cross-origin resource sharing is a mechanism that allows restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was served. A web page may freely embed cross-origin images, stylesheets, scripts, iframes, and videos. -*Wikipedia*

So do a `npm install --save cors` and use the code below

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cors = require('cors');

let app = express();
let port = 3000

app.use(cors()); // add cors to middleware

app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
// for parsing application/json which was stringified in the ajax front-end

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get('/api/test', function (req, res) {
   res.send("<h1>WOrking</h1>")
})

app.post('/api/test', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.body)
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`));
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve this yesterday. I appreciate all the help.

It turns out that i needed to add the following code to my express body parser:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```